# Ways for combining Adobe AIR and Python - Python

Tags: python, air, desktop-application

**I need to use Python because:** I have implemented many scripts and libraries using Python in order to solve a certain problem.

**I would like to use AIR because:** I really love the flexibility of building UIs using HTML and Javascript, also implementing beautiful UI designs is actually very easy.

Any ideas if I can integrate these 2 technologies or if not, any ideas how I could substitute AIR?

---

Help would be awesome! :)

Comment: Why does the question title say "Python - Python"?

Comment: @S.Lott I always write my questions as "Question - Topic"

Comment: @RadientHex: And it doesn't seem redundant in this specific instance?   Particularly when the tags repeat the "topic"?

Comment: @S.Lott the redundancy striked me too late. I apologise sir.

Comment: And you see no reason to fix the redundancy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been thinking about the same combo as well.  [PyAMF](http://pyamf.org/) might be worth a look - I've been thinking of PyAMF + web2py + AIR myself, possibly with py2exe thrown in for good measure.

Comment: that looks pretty interesting! So PyAMF is used to communicate with adobe AIR, web2py is used to create the http server and backend of the app and adobe AIR is used as UI? How would you go on about installing everything together? I reckon that getting the user to install each individually would be pretty daunting. Thanks for this awesome reply :)

Comment: @RadiantHex:  Glad it helped!  My first thought was to keep Python on the server side, but I'm thinking you could also compile it to a standalone app with py2exe.  Adobe's got an article on how to bundle native applications within the AIR package here:  http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/quickstart/interacting_with_native_process.html .

Comment: I am truly thankful! Seems like it could be slightly long winded. I'll tick this answer as I believe it answers my question fully! :) Have you already built software using the methods you re suggesting? If not I would be interested in collaborating on a standardized solution. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @RadiantHex:  So far I'm still in the thinking/experimenting stage - playing with Python's SimpleHTTPServer and a RIA UI, that sort of thing; I use py2exe fairly frequently but I haven't tried PyAMF as of yet.  I've packed native code w. AIR following Adobe's writeup - it is a little fiddly but I've seen worse.  I'm game for collaboration, seems like it'd end up being a fairly simple recipe more than anything.  Oh and you might also check out Titanium Desktop @ http://www.appcelerator.com/, that's another option for Python + HTML/Javascript UI.